# Google Cloud Storage API and Resumeable Uploads returning null Location header

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get the Location header for resumeable uploads using the Google Cloud Storage JSON API as described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable, but I am always getting response code 400 Bad Request. I know I am making a stupid mistake somewhere along the line, but I just cannot see where this is happening, so if anybody has gotten this to work successfully or can point me to what I am missing that would be a great help.

Here is my request code:

```
private static final String RESUMEABLE_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/%s/o?uploadType=resumable"

public String getLocationForResumeableUpload(String filename, ResourceType resourceType, String contentType, Long contentLength) throws EndpointException {
    String resumeableUploadURL = String.format(RESUMEABLE_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT,
            getBucketForResourceType(resourceType).getBucketName());

    try {
        URL uploadURL = new URL(resumeableUploadURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uploadURL.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type", contentType);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length", "" + contentLength);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        String json = "{\"name\":\"" + filename + "\"}";
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(json.getBytes().length));

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control");
        AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken =
                AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getAccessToken(scopes);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
        connection.connect();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            log.debug("connection failed with accessToken: " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
            log.debug(connection.getResponseMessage());
            throw new NotFoundException("Object at url: " + resumeableUploadURL +
                    " returns response code: " + connection.getResponseCode() + " response message: " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        String locationHeader = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        log.debug("Upload request response: " + responseMessage + " Location header: " + locationHeader);
        return locationHeader;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("URL Malformed: " + resumeableUploadURL + " unable to fetch resumeable upload url", e);
        throw new InternalServerException("Unable to complete upload request", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Unable to fetch upload URL from GCS: " + resumeableUploadURL, e);
        throw new InternalServerException("Unable to complete upload request", e);
    }
}
```

**Update 1:** Turns out I had a bug in my code, I was checking for response code > 400 and the request is returning response code: 400 - Bad Request. So now my question is, why is my request bad?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the name of the object needs to be put in the query string like this:

```
private static final String RESUMEABLE_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/%s/o?uploadType=resumable&name=%s"
```

So the full piece of code looks like this:

```
public String getLocationForResumeableUpload(String filename, ResourceType resourceType, String contentType, Long contentLength) throws EndpointException {
    String resumeableUploadURL = String.format(RESUMEABLE_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT,
            getBucketForResourceType(resourceType).getBucketName(), filename);

    try {
        URL uploadURL = new URL(resumeableUploadURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uploadURL.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type", contentType);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length", "" + contentLength);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(0));

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control");
        AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken =
                AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getAccessToken(scopes);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
        connection.connect();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            log.debug("connection failed with accessToken: " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
            log.debug(connection.getResponseMessage());
            throw new NotFoundException("Object at url: " + resumeableUploadURL +
                    " returns response code: " + connection.getResponseCode() + " response message: " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        String locationHeader = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        log.debug("Upload request response " + connection.getResponseCode() + " : " + responseMessage + " Location header: " + locationHeader);
        return locationHeader;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("URL Malformed: " + resumeableUploadURL + " unable to fetch resumeable upload url", e);
        throw new InternalServerException("Unable to complete upload request", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Unable to fetch upload URL from GCS: " + resumeableUploadURL, e);
        throw new InternalServerException("Unable to complete upload request", e);
    }
}
```